# Need to get records from db for current date(excluding time)

Tags: sql, oracle, date, for-loop, criteria

I have written below query to get the records:

```
Select * 
  from Scf_Invoice i 
 where cast(i.inv_Acceptance_Date as date) = TO_DATE('2018-12-18', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

But, I get no resultseven if there are 2 records for the given date. I think it's considering time also. When I do

```
Select * 
  from Scf_Invoice i 
 where cast(i.inv_Acceptance_Date as date) > TO_DATE('2018-12-18', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

I get the results, But I want those results using ' = ' parameter. What change should I do in my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [trunc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm) to get day

```
  trunc(i.inv_Acceptance_Date) =
```

> The TRUNC (date) function returns date with the time portion of the day truncated to the unit specified by the format model fmt. The value returned is always of datatype DATE, even if you specify a different datetime datatype for date. If you omit fmt, then date is **truncated to the nearest day**.

```
Select * 
from Scf_Invoice i 
where trunc(i.inv_Acceptance_Date) = TO_DATE('2018-12-18', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Problem resolved 50 %. Now it gives me correct result in SQLDeveloper. But, when I try to run it from my Spring Boot Application, it throws an error. Caused by: org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException:
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [Select i from ScfInvoice i where trunc(i.invAcceptanceDate) = to_date('2018-12-18', 'YYYY-MM-DD')].
[33, 99] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.

Comment: @JavaProgrammer show the error and how you exe ute it in code, you might missing a space or typo

Comment: @JavaProgrammer what's `Select i `? You mean  `i.columnName`?

Comment: ScfInvoiceRepository invoiceRepository;
   String invoiceQuery = "Select i from ScfInvoice i where trunc(i.invAcceptanceDate) = TO_DATE('"
     + currentBusinessDate + "', 'YYYY-MM-DD')";
   List<ScfInvoice> invoiceList = invoiceRepository.executeQuery(invoiceQuery); This is my code. I have written native query for my entity class(ScfInvoice) and currentBusinessDate is today's date.

Comment: @JavaProgrammer you didn't change cast to trunc in code

Comment: Problem resolved. Issue was with SQL functions in JPQL query. I modified my query to "Select i from ScfInvoice i where func('TRUNC', i.invAcceptanceDate) = func('to_date', '2018-12-18', 'YYYY-MM-DD')". Now its working fine. Thanks a lot. You helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
  from Scf_Invoice i 
 where trunc(i.inv_Acceptance_Date) = TO_DATE('2018-12-18', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

or

```
Select * 
  from Scf_Invoice i 
 where trunc(i.inv_Acceptance_Date) = trunc(sysdate);
```

for get data equal curent date